# In Android Studio The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

At first I was not able to access my xml element id's directly inside main activity. Then I used **'kotlin-android-extensions'** Gradle plugin and the issue was solved but while running the application I'm getting above error message

I've used -

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    }
```